# is Xamarin.foms have Xaml designer yet?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I started learning Xamarin with visual studio 2015, but in building multiplateform applications using xamarin.forms, I don't see any Xaml designer to help me inserting elements and layouts on the pages, I must write elements one by one?

I have read that a preview for elements will be in new version of xamarin (2016), but I don't see it in visual studio.

Any one have some infos about that?

Thanks for any information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Xamarin.Forms have designer support on VS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999026/does-xamarin-forms-have-designer-support-on-vs)

Answer (score 2):

According ebook "Creating Mobile Apps with Xamarin.Forms" pg. 132:

> When creating XAML for Microsoft platforms, some developers use
>   interactive design tools such as Microsoft Blend, but many others
>   prefer to handwrite XAML. No design tools are available for Xamarin.
>   Forms, so handwriting is the only option. Obviously, all the XAML
>   examples in this book are handwritten. But even when design tools are
>   available, the ability to handwrite XAML is an important skill.

Comment: Handwriting is the best way and you have a real understanding of the code that you made.