# can't drag Toolbox control to new IOS XAML app

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

Started new IOS XAML App project "App1".
Double-clicked MainPage.xaml
 Clicked Design button on upper right.

It showed "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"

Opened VS Toolbox, but when I click and try to drag any control over the design pane, it shows the black-circle-with-slash.

Double-click Toolbox control doesn't do anything.

Using...
Visual Studio 2017 Pro
on Windows 10 Pro
VS is connected to my MacBook.

Comment: Are you using the `XAML previewer`?  It seems you can not drag-and-drop interface builder for `xaml` right now. You can drag-and-drop codes in the `.xaml` file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is currently drag-and-drop interface builder for Xamarin.Forms. See [Does Xamarin.Forms have designer support on VS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999026/does-xamarin-forms-have-designer-support-on-vs/37999101#37999101) and several others.